# Is it possible to store an error cause in a struct without an enum?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a library in Rust and would like the API to only expose my own error type, with any errors caused by libraries used internally wrapped in that type. I want to implement the `Error` trait and expose the original error as the "cause". I can do this with an enum by doing something like:

```
enum MyErrorCause {
    Zip(ZipError),
    Io(IoError),
    None
}

pub struct MyError {
    cause: MyErrorCause
}

impl Error for MyError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str { "an error" }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> {
        match self.cause {
            MyErrorCause::Zip(ref err) => Some(err as &Error),
            MyErrorCause::Io(ref err) => Some(err as &Error),
            MyErrorCause::None => None
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to add an enum variant and virtually identical match arm for every cause type, when I'm only ever exposing them to the user as a generic `Error` reference. Is it possible to store the cause as `Error` in the `MyError` struct? I would still like the cause to be owned by `MyError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the overhead of allocating memory for each error, you could store an `Option<Box<Error + 'static>>` as the cause.  When you're creating the `MyError`, just use `Some(Box::new(the_cause) as Box<Error>`.  The `'static` bound is to let the compiler know that any errors you store must not have short-lived references inside them.

Another alternative would be to write a macro that expands to the required `enum` and `impl`, but that seems somewhat overkill.

Comment: What does "short-lived" mean with regards to references? I'd seen something using `Box` and a static lifetime elsewhere but thought that meant the value had to be a constant/known at compile time.

Comment: @David: `'static` as a constraint for a type means that the type does not contain any references less than `'static` in lifetime. So `i32` and `String` are fine because they own their data and contain no references, and `&'static str` is fine because although it has a reference it is static.